# css switching background image on hover

Tags: css

I'm going to risk sounding dumb and just ask because this is driving me crazy.

I have a bunch of links that have icons attached to links, but one of them has to be an image. I can make the image appear just fine, but the hover just does not seem to want to work.

I know it has to be something stupid I'm doing, but I could really use some help.

My html looks like this

```
<ul class="socials">
  <li class='reverb'><a href="#"></a></li>
</ul>
```

and my css looks like this

```
.socials li a{
    display:inline-block;
    width:48px;
    height:48px;
    font-size:32px;
    line-height:48px;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    color:#fff;
    -webkit-transition:color 0.2s ease-out;
    transition:color 0.2s ease-out;


}


.reverb a:link{
    background: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/archive/f/f4/20090120040123!Free_Blue_Star.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-size: 45px 45px;
}

.reverb a:hover{
    background: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/34/Red_star.svg
') no-repeat;
    background-size: 45px 45px;

}
```

and a fiddle to help. http://jsfiddle.net/foj82s1z/1/

Any help would be amazing!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change following:

```
.reverb a:hover{
    background: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/34/Red_star.svg
') no-repeat;
    background-size: 45px 45px;

}
```

To this:

```
.reverb a:hover{
    background: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/34/Red_star.svg') no-repeat;
    background-size: 45px 45px;
}
```

There was a line break in your code. Check this [fixed working example](http://jsfiddle.net/foj82s1z/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Getting rid of the line break in the middle of your background statement fixes it:

```
.reverb a:hover{
    background: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/34/Red_star.svg') no-repeat;
    background-size: 45px 45px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works just fine, make sure you clear the whitespace.

```
.reverb a:hover{
    background: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/34/Red_star.svg') no-repeat;
    background-size: 45px 45px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the white-space from the image url

```
background: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/34/Red_star.svg') no-repeat;
```

On your fiddle the line break was causing problem.